# What should the .help file extension be registered to on OS X?

Tags: macos, file-extension, help-files

I recently got a package of `.help` manual files for a device.  Unfortunately, some gremlin has decided these files should open with "Disk Inventory X", which gets thrown into an absolute transport by the attempt.

What application should .help open with, so I can read my manuals?

Comment: .help or .hlp ?

Comment: Definitely .help

Comment: `.help` isn't a standard extension that I'm familiar with, it's possible that they're just plain text files. Have you tried to open them in TextEdit or a similar program? What do the files look like if you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'files' are actually directories formatted as OS X's package directories, so they were hidden by finder.  Several levels in, there is at least one HTML page.  I still have to suspect something went awry in the install process and left them with the wrong open method.